# Show that $3a^2-5b^2=1$ has no integer solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

Consider the equation $3a^2-5b^2=1$. Show that this has no integer solutions.
My hunch is to use a fact that I proved earlier: that $x^2=0$,$1$ or $4$ mod $5$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Assume for contradiction that the claim is true (ie. that two integer solutions do exist). Then, we can write $3a^2-5b^2\in $ {$0$ mod $5$, $2$ mod $5$, $3$ mod $5$} (I'll call this set $S$). This comes from combining the fact that I proved earlier with some algebra. Then, I eliminate the mathematical duplicates in the set so that it consists of as few elements as possible. Since $3a^2-5b^2=1$ as assumed, $1$ must be able to be written in a form so that $1\in S$. Yet, $1=1$ mod $5$, and $1$ mod $5\notin S$, a contradiction.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks just fine, although you don't need to assume two solutions exist, just that one does (one solution is an integer *pair* $(a,b)$ satisfying the equation). Also note that $3a^2 - 5b^2\equiv 3a^2\pmod{5}$, so that the possible values of $3a^2 - 5b^2$ modulo $5$ are just $\{3\cdot 0\pmod{5}, 3\cdot 1\pmod{5}, 3\cdot 4\pmod{5}\} = \{0\pmod{5},3\pmod{5},2\pmod{5}\}$ so there's no removing of duplicates involved.